# iPad E-Mail Attachments are destroyed on the Exchange account

Tags: ios, email, pdf, exchange

I have a problem with my ipad Air iOS 7.0.4. When I receive E-Mails on my Exchange account, which contain for example a .pdf, the pdf is destroyed an can't be opend. If I forward the attachment, the attachment is still destroyed on the other recipient. I also receive my exchange mails on my PC and there are the attachments fully functional.

On my iPad I have a second GMX Imap account, and if I send a attachment to this account, I also receive it fully functional.

I already tried to delete the Exchange account from  the iPad and added it newly.

Comment: What is **destroyed**? You're vague.

Answer (score -1):

I have exactly the same problem and deleted the Exchange account but this did not solve the problem. The Apple Store has never heard of this problem. Their suggestion was to restore to factory defaults.